# Is there any "How to build simple web app with Joomla Framework for dummies" tutorial?

Tags: joomla-framework-1.x, joomla-framework

I need to create a simple landing page that is displaying dynamic portfolio items and some simple data which are taken from database + a contact form.

I think Joomla CMS is somewhat overkill for that purpose, as I don't need complex user management, ACL and other Joomla CMS features. So then I'm start to think that maybe I can use Joomla Framework for that.

I have tried to google it but not really found a good tutorial about how to create single web application using Joomla Framework, especially for dummies like me.

Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest not using the Framework. Its going to take you a long time to understand, as there is very little implementation orientated documents, there are few people using it so your chance of support is low etc.
Sometimes its worth investing time to understand a new technology. If that's your aim then pick a framework that is being actively developed and used by a lot of people - Laraval springs to mind as a good suggestion.

If all you want is to create the site, then you could probably find a portfolio and contact component for joomla and have the site up in a day. Alternatively use a CCK (Fabrik (disclaimer I'm one of the dev's), Seblod, etc) which would allow you to create a porfolio page without having to code.

Comment: Ah I see, so my understanding of Joomla Framework is completely wrong. I was thinking Joomla Framework is something that will grow just like other php frameworks such as laravel, ci, yii etc so a joomla developer who are  already familiar with joomla doesn't need to migrate to other framework when their skill is growing.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a lot of documentation on this, however each individual framework package has it's own "Getting Started" section so you can see how it's used:

https://github.com/joomla-framework

The only documentation Wiki I could find were the following:

- https://docs.joomla.org/Framework:Getting_Started
- https://docs.joomla.org/Framework:Creating_a_Stand-alone_Application

There is a Sample Application on Github created by David Hurley, however the last commit was in November 2014:

https://github.com/dbhurley/framework-app

There have been some fairly big changes in the framework, so I'm not sure if this should be used as an actual sample.

Comment: Maybe you can start one? @Lodder :D

Comment: @webchun - Haha, maybe, but it would take me a long time. I'm not a back-end developer. I'll ask a few people if there is a sample app with the latest framework

Comment: @webchun - Just asked and unfortunately there isn't. Sorry

Comment: Maybe check: https://github.com/joomla/framework.joomla.org